# Masonry horizontal layout stacking oddly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've been fiddling with this for more than an hour now, I've also did some search and review some that was posted here but non of them was able to resolve my issue.

I have 5 divs and the third and forth div doesn't stack up as I was expecting, instead the last div stack on the third div.

http://jsbin.com/rajinabu

**HTML**

```
  <div class="isotope js-isotope">
      <div class="item width2 height2"></div>
      <div class="item width2 height2"></div>
      <div class="item width2 width2"></div>
      <div class="item width2 width2"></div>
      <div class="item width2 height2"></div>  
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
layoutMode: "masonryHorizontal", 
itemSelector: ".boxes", 
masonryHorizontal: { rowHeight: 360 } 

});
```

*I was expecting it to behave something like this,*

[image]

Comment: I have the some issue. Did you solve the problem? If so, it will be good if you can share it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not see the jQuery library getting used. Check your console. I am getting the error: "$ is not defined." You should also be wrapping your initialization in

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   YOUR CODE HERE    });
```

of some other closure.

Comment: whoops, I put a linked a different version. It's fixed now. Although, I did wrapped my code on Domready